# Allow copy-paste into MS Remote Desktop, but not copy from there?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a Microsoft Remote Desktop connecting to a server.

Is it possible to enable copy-pasting from my local computer into the remote windows, but disable it the other way round?

(this way it would be harder to export data from the remote machine)

Comment: Question should be asked on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Like @paj28 indicated it's not possible to limit the Clipboard functionality one way.

You would need to disable it completely.